# Shuffling Adapter List not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a gridview of 8 textview elements that I am trying to shuffle by using:

```
public void Shuffle(View v) {

    Collections.shuffle(stringList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Each textview has three 'states' so to speak: A letter (it's text), a color, and whether it's currently clickable or unclickable. When I shuffle the elements, the letter changes, but not their color or clickableness.

So if the first 4 elements are:

A (red, clickable),

B (blue, unclickable),

C (blue, unclickable),

D (red, clickable),

and I call the shuffle function, I might get:

C (red, clickable),

A (blue, unclickable),

D (blue, unclickable),

B (red, clickable).

It seems that the text of the textview is able to be shuffled but the color and clickableness are rooted to the position on the screen and not to the textview. I think it might have something to do with the way these attributes are assigned, but I can't really see how. Here is the pertinent code:

```
GridView gridView;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> stringList;
private static final String[] LETTERSET = generateLetterset.main();
```

...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Letterset buttons logic
        stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(LETTERSET));
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lettersGrid);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.letter_text_view_item, stringList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                TextView wordConstructor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wordConstructor);
                wordConstructor.setText(wordConstructor.getText().toString() + ((TextView) v).getText());

                 v.setClickable(true);
                ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

            }

        });
```

Comment: you need to create a custom adapter to solve this

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate? I'm not really sure why this code isn't working. As far as my understanding, this should work. What does a custom adapter do for me that this can't?